# Какие есть альтернативы lookbehind для javascript

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

```
var str = 'abcde abcde';
```

Как составить выражение, по условию которого нужно выбрать cde перед которым обязательно находится ab?
Так-как в js нет **"назад смотрящих"**, значит нужно осуществлять поиск с символов 'ab' и смотреть, что идет за ними, но не включая эти символы в результат.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/ab(cde)/g
```

**[Пример использования](http://jsfiddle.net/LUK27/1/)**

```
function preg_match_all(regex, haystack) {
   var globalRegex = new RegExp(regex, 'g');
   var globalMatch = haystack.match(globalRegex);
   matchArray = new Array();
   for (var i in globalMatch) {
      nonGlobalRegex = new RegExp(regex);
      nonGlobalMatch = globalMatch[i].match(nonGlobalRegex);
      matchArray.push(nonGlobalMatch[1]);
   }
   return matchArray;
}

var str = 'abcde abcde abcde f'; 
var re = 'ab(cde)';
console.log(preg_match_all(re, str)); 
//Array [ "cde", "cde", "cde" ]
```

**[Подтверждение того, что регулярное выражение было изначально рабочим](http://regex101.com/r/vM1zQ4/1#javascript)**

**[Имитирование lookbehind в javascript 1](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript)**
**[Имитирование lookbehind в javascript 2](https://gist.github.com/slevithan/2387872)**

Comment: Уважаемый @vas, проблема не в регулярном выражении, а в том, как вы его используете.

Comment: @VenZell, то есть, для такого легкого шаблона создание нагромаждения, это в js нормально?

Comment: А создавать в цикле один и тот же RegExp?)
И у Вас подтверждение того, что выражение ищет abcde вместо cde.

Comment: @VenZell,  я в js новичок, но Вы видно нет и по этому я хочу у Вас спросить уже спрошенное - для js нормально делать вот такие кульбиты с вырезаннием и созданием массивов, перебора и прочего? Или Вы это только показали, но сами бы использовать не стали?

Comment: @vas, вы сами указали на существующую проблему: отсутствие в javascript позитивного (или негативного) просмотра назад для регулярных выражений.  
Соответственно, придется изгаляться, чтобы обойти эту особенность.  
Добавил альтернативные варианты в ответ.

Относительно вашего последнего комментария: зависит от поставленной задачи, стал бы я это использовать или нет. Возможно, задачу можно решить проще (без использования регулярок). 
А вообще, я очень сильно сомневаюсь, что данная функция, даст сильный удар по производительности.

Comment: @VenZell, Спасибо! Я пока читать и разбираться. Если что, то потом вернусь и спрошу.

Answer (score 3):

В общем виде универсальной альтернативы нет, но как показывает практика всегда можно создать регулярное выражение без lookbehind, хоть оно и получится монстроподобным.